# Not able to pull all comments from instagram comments endpoints

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-requests, instagram, instagram-api

Hi right now I am using the comment endpoint https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/{media-id}/comments?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN

but it seems that I'm only getting my comments on a picture and not what everyone else is commenting? Does the comments endpoint only grab my comments and not anyone else? I'm using python.

Comment: Can you provide the response you are getting from the Instagram API. The endpoint documentation says you should get a **list of recent comments on a media object** and says nothing about just your own.

Comment: Please post your code and the erroneous data you're receiving, such that we can test for ourselves.

Comment: you are in sandbox mode, so u will only see your comments, its expected, you can read about sandbox mode on the website

Comment: I think it is a sandbox thing. So while in sandbox mode you can only pull comments and likes that you make?